# Is there any way to store field value only once?

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to store (while inserting) a value on column which can never be changed ?

Like example :

insert to DB row "a,b,c,x,s,**X**"  - and the **X** **wont** be able to change.
(however , if the whole row is deleted - its fine"

Comment: There are good options listed here, but it should be remembered that someone with SA level access can remove any attempt to prevent the change if they so chose.  For someone with SA level access, any attempt to make a column unchaneable would just be a suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a trigger before updating or after updating  ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188601.aspx ) the rows to check whether it is going to change or not. Here is an example trigger after update , it will rollback transaction if column modified.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_update on YourTable AFTER UPDATE AS
    IF UPDATE(YourColumn)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('cannot change yourColumn', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RETURN
    END
GO
```

Answer (score 4):

You can remove UPDATE privilieges for that column from the users you don't want to be able to change the value. Alternatively, use an update trigger to prevent updates.

The update trigger is easier if you want to disallow updates from any user.

Comment: Either option would work, but the performance and complexity price of the trigger is higher so removing the update for that column is the better option.

Answer (score 2):

Add an Update Trigger, where you check for a change:

```
CREATE TRIGGER YourTrigger On YourTable FOR UPDATE
AS

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM INSERTED           i
                   INNER JOIN DELETED  d ON i.PK=d.PK
               WHERE i.columnX!=d.columnX 
                   OR (i.columnX IS NULL and d.columnx IS NOT NULL)
                   OR (d.columnX IS NULL and i.columnx IS NOT NULL) 
          )
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK
    RAISERROR('Error, can''t change columnX',16,1)
    RETURN
END

GO
```